# how to read the parameter with params keyword and implementing a function

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hi I have here a code snippet. This isn't mine, I saw this in the internet while learning on how to deal with `Entity Framework` I know it just including (eager load) the navigation properties then return it as `IQueryable`

What I want to know is:

1. How do you read this parameter `params System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties`?
2. How do you call or use this function? (Should pass collection, am I right? A little example would be a great help since I learn in a way when I see some demo)

   ```
   public IQueryable<Customer> AllIncluding(params System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
   {
       var query = context.Customers;
       foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
       {
           query = query.Include(includeProperty);
       }

       return query;
   }
   ```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: When you looked up the documentation on the `params` keyword what did you find, and what specific aspects of it did you find confusing?

Comment: Regarding #1: I wouldn't really read that whole thing aloud, but I often speak of a method taking a "params array" as an argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`params` lets you pass an array parameter as an actual array or an open-ended list of values:

```
var includes = new Expression<Func<Customer, object>>[] 
    { 
        i => i.SubProperty1, 
        i => i.SubProperty2
    };
var query = db.Entities.AllIncluding(includes);
```

or just

```
var query = db.Entities.AllIncluding(i => i.SubProperty1, i => i.SubProperty2);
```

I'm guessing on the specific types and properties, but hopefully you get the idea.